# possible to have separate factor levels for each axis in one graph?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom, ggforce, ggalluvial

I'm trying to plot a Sankey diagram of financial flows between a source country and counterpart country.

```
ggplot(dat_ggforce, aes(x=x, id=id, split = y, value=yvalue)) +
geom_parallel_sets(aes(fill = cpcountryname), alpha = alpha, axis.width = 0.2,
                   n=100, strength = 0.6)
```

I order countryname and cpcountryname using factor levels

```
dat$countryname <- factor(dat$countryname, levels = c("Indonesia", "Malaysia", "Philippines", "Singapore", "Thailand"))
dat$cpcountryname <- factor(dat$cpcountryname, levels = c("United States","United Kingdom","Japan","Malaysia", "Others")
```

However, because Malaysia is in both the left and right axis, Malaysia suddenly overrides the right axis, as such:

[image: Malaysia is at top instead of 5th stratum]

Edit: The order for counterparty country is based on flow size (US > UK > JP > MY, then others). Malaysia should be below Japan on the right axis as seen in the factor levels for cpcountryname, but keeps moving to the top.

Edit2: I have narrowed the problem. My actual question is, is it possible to have separate factor levels for each axis in one graph?

Comment: Hi Benedict. It's not clear from your question what the expected output is.

Comment: Thanks Allan, added the edit section.

Comment: Edited: I have narrowed the problem. My actual question is, is it possible to have separate factor levels for each axis in one ggplot graph?